Visual Studio winforms app sends trace messages to seperate message boxes
I'm developing a Windows forms app using C# in Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.11.5
When I try and edit a form using the GUI Visual Studio sends debug and trace messages to message boxes like that here.
Trace listener message:

The output window shows the message -
trce: Notifying 1 'UI/ShowMessage' handlers

Getting one might be okay but it's throwing dozens of these messages before it opens the form for editing.
Any help would be much appreciated.
I have tried porting code to new solution but it still has the problem.
To reproduce the problem
Create custom control using Windows Forms Control Library for .NET
Add control load event
private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}

In same solution add a new Windows Forms App and using GUI add the custom control. Doesn't need any code other than that produced by Visual Studio.
When you open the form for editing it displays the message from the Trace Listener.
Hello World message:


Have you considered just adding if (!DesignMode) Trace.WriteLine("Hello world!");, until the issue is resolved (you wouldn't believe why this thing is happening)

This appears to be either how Windows Forms works now or an issue that they won't fix - see this Github issue.
You can work around it by removing the default trace listener and adding your own. So, in the Load event for your UserControl:
Trace.Listeners.RemoveAt(0);
Trace.Listeners.Add(new DefaultTraceListener { LogFileName = @"c:\temp\trace.log" });
Trace.WriteLine($"{ DateTime.Now.ToString() }");

That will just dump any Trace and Debug output into the file specified, which you can refer to or ignore as needed.
Of course this would probably be better done in the initialisation stage of the whole application rather than everywhere you might want to call Trace or Debug.

A good suggestion although I ended up using Trace.Listeners.Clear(); to nuke all trace and debug messages.

The problem is that Trace.WriteLine is used in the Load event of the custom control. When you add and open the control through the designer in a Windows Forms application, the designer will also trigger this Load event, causing the debug message pop-up window. After my test, if you want to avoid this phenomenon, you can add a DesignMode check in the UserControl1_Load event:
private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!this.DesignMode)
   {
       Trace.WriteLine("Hello world!");
   }
}


A good work around. I have no problem with Trace itself but I don't want each message going to a message box that I need to click on Okay to dismiss.

Thanks for your reply, if this solution worked for you, please mark it as the answer. If you found another solution yourself, you can post it and accept your own answer so that if others encounter a similar problem, they can find the solution faster.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

It looks to me that the GUI designer in Visual Studio 17.11.5 is broken and I hope it get fixed in future versions. I am using a third party control that makes extensive use of tracing and it takes 122 clicks of Okay buttons to bring up the form with this control.
Until it get fixed the answers by Alan B and Cody Laing provide work arounds.

This bug will be fixed in 17.13 preview 1 of VS.
https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/12360
